# How can I get the contents of the last message sent on a discord server

Tags: python-3.x, discord

I'm trying to set up a discord bot where it basically repeats what a user says under certain conditions. For the sake of simplicity, the conditions don't matter in the question. My current strategy is to get the logs when the condition is met and then repeat them. However, my code isn't working. I'm using python 3.6.4 (I haven't set up the repeat yet, I just want to get the last message sent.)
Here is my code:

```
import discord

TOKEN = 'XXXXXXXX'

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('I am'):
        msg = 'Hi {0.author.mention}'.format(message)
        await client.send_message(message.channel, msg)
    if message.content.startswith('Logs'):
        logs= logs_from(general, limit=1)
        print(logs)

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as')
    print(client.user.name)
    print(client.user.id)
    print('------')

client.run(TOKEN)
```

The issue is at

```
logs=logs_from(general, limit=1)
```

Here is the error

```
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 307, in _run_event
yield from getattr(self, event)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "dadbot.py", line 17, in on_message
    logs= logs_from(general, limit=1)
NameError: name 'logs_from' is not defined
```

Keep in mind this is my first discord bot and I'm struggling to find helpful info online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `logs_from` is never defined, so you get the error.

Probably you mean:

```
logs = client.logs_from(general, limit=1)
```

so, you want the method `log_from`, from the client class.

Comment: Thanks so much, this worked, but then general is undefined even though I certainly have a text server called general. I know this wasn't part of the original question, but can you help me?

Comment: I see one one `general` string in the above code (and used as value), so `general` is not defined. Python is string on namespace, and so code is also readable. From the code above, I have no idea of what `general` could mean/contain.

Comment: You need probable a general = client.get_channel(...some...id).